# EF 6 Save related entity composite key

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6

I have the following EF Entities:

```
public class EmployeeHoliday
    {

        public int HolidayId { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    }

    public class EmployeeHolidayItem
        {
            public int HolidayId { get; set; }
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
            public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
            public string MasterEntity { get; set; }
            public bool IsRealHoliday { get; set; }
            public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        }
```

The EF Configuration Map are:

```
public EmployeeHolidayMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => t.HolidayId);

            // Properties
            this.Property(t => t.HolidayId)
               .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

            // Properties
            this.Property(t => t.EmployeeId)
                .IsRequired();

            // Table & Column Mappings
            this.ToTable("employee_holiday");
            this.Property(t => t.HolidayId).HasColumnName("holidayid");
            this.Property(t => t.EmployeeId).HasColumnName("employeeid");
            this.Property(t => t.StartDate).HasColumnName("startdate");
            this.Property(t => t.EndDate).HasColumnName("enddate");
            this.Property(t => t.IsActive).HasColumnName("isactive");

        }




public EmployeeHolidayItemMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => new { t.HolidayId, t.Date });

            this.Property(t => t.EmployeeId)
              .IsRequired();

            this.Property(t => t.MasterEntity)
             .IsRequired();


            // Table & Column Mappings
            this.ToTable("employee_holiday_item");
            this.Property(t => t.HolidayId).HasColumnName("holidayid");
            this.Property(t => t.Date).HasColumnName("date");
            this.Property(t => t.EmployeeId).HasColumnName("employeeid");
            this.Property(t => t.MasterEntity).HasColumnName("masterentity");
            this.Property(t => t.IsRealHoliday).HasColumnName("isrealholiday");
            this.Property(t => t.IsActive).HasColumnName("isactive");
        }
```

Now Im trying to Save a new `EmployeeHoliday` with a few `EmployeeHolidayItems`  but I get an error with the `HolidayId` key in the EmployeeHolidayItems model.

This is the code for inserting a new `EmployeeHoliday`:

```
int holidayId = 0;

var newRequest = new Model.EmployeeHoliday();

                newRequest.HolidayId = holidayId;

                newRequest.EmployeeId = request.EmployeeId;
                newRequest.StartDate = dates.FirstOrDefault();
                newRequest.EndDate = dates.LastOrDefault();
                newRequest.IsActive = true;


var newRequestDates = new List<Model.EmployeeHolidayItem>();

// Add Days to Holiday Item
                foreach (var date in dates)
                {
                    var newDate = new Model.EmployeeHolidayItem();

                    newDate.HolidayId = holidayId;
                    newDate.EmployeeId = request.EmployeeId;
                    newDate.MasterEntity = Uow.MasterEntity;
                    newDate.Date = date;
                    newDate.IsRealHoliday = true; 
                    newDate.IsActive = true;

                    // add to list
                    newRequestDates.Add(newDate);
                }

DbContext.EmployeeHoliday.Add(newRequest);
DbContext.EmployeeHolidayItem.AddRange(newRequestDates);

DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

> Is there a way I can force the relation between EmployeeHoliday and EmployeeHolidayItem when inserting new record? I don't want to make the relation in my Mapping.

Comment: why don't you add a `EmployeHolidayItem` collection property on `EmployeeHoliday` class ?

Comment: I that the correct way to do it?

Comment: yes it should be, because by adding a collection inside EmployeeHoliday, EF will track all graph objects underneath it, and you don't have to set the `EmployeHolidayId` when inserting new `EmployeeHolidayItem`, EF will take care the id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this property on `EmployeeHoliday` class.

```
public class EmployeeHoliday
{
   public ICollection<EmployeeHolidayItem> EmployeeHolidayItems {get;set;}
}
```

And replace this

```
DbContext.EmployeeHoliday.Add(newRequest);
DbContext.EmployeeHolidayItem.AddRange(newRequestDates);
```

with

```
newRequest.EmployeeHolidayItems = newRequestDates;
DbContext.EmployeeHoliday.Add(newRequest);
```